# How can I write the rows that meet my condition while keeping my data intact

Tags: python

The problem is im not sure how to convert the data that matches my if condition to 1 , I can print it out but how can actually write it to the file without messing up my other data. Here is the output of the data that matches my if condition. Any advice to write it to another file?

```
- query environment variable
- get file size
- read file on Windows
- read file via mapping
- get thread local storage value
- terminate process
- link function at runtime on Windows
- linked against ZLIB
```

**Code:**

```py
with open("your_output3.csv", 'r') as csv_file_obj:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file_obj)
    heading = next(csv_file_obj).strip().split(",")
    reader_obj = csv.reader(csv_file_obj)
    for row in reader_obj:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            # Make sure that we skip the first 2 columns
            if i < 2:
                continue
            if row[i] in headers:
                #row[i] = 1
                print(row[i])
```

Comment: Generally, you'll just want to write to another file (`your_output3_processed.csv`, for instance). Reading and writing to the same file at the same time can be done but it's complicated and requires special care. And if this is going to be run from a command line, having two separate files makes it easier to pipe data to and from other programs anyway.

Comment: how can I do it in py since the issue is I want all the data from the other file as well

Comment: Given a csv file, you want to generate a new one with the first two columns removed. Is that correct?

Comment: label md5 create new key via CryptAcquireContext delete user account group send file via HTTP send data stop service encrypt data using DES via WinAPI suspend thread get file size encrypt data using RC4 via WinAPI
malware 0e498d2283a99aad9a997200caf2f24e packed with UPX 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
I need to convert features to one

Comment: There's no need to loop over the columns, just use a slice: `writer.writerow(row[2:])`.

Comment: @jack_dan Is that comment supposed to be English? Comments have no formatting, so don't try to paste a file in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read and write the same file if you're using the `csv` module to parse it. So write the output to a new file.

To skip the first two columns of the file, you can use a slice of the row when writing.

```
with open('input.csv', 'r') as infile, open('output.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)

    heading = next(reader)
    writer.writerow(heading[2:])

    for row in reader:
        if condition(row):
            writer.writerow(row[2:])
```